# WPF Как составить коллекцию Combobox из файлов проекта

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Как можно составить коллекцию ComboBox'a из названий файлов, которые находятся в папке Resources/Products?

```
ComboBox.ItemsSource = ????
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вставьте код текстом. Перепечатывать код с картинки чтобы создать пример - так себе удовольствие.

Comment: 2 слова сложно написать? Хорошо, учтём.

Comment: 1) правила такие, 2) дело не только в перепечатывании. `ComboBox.ItemsSource = Directory.GetFiles(path).Select(p => Path.GetFileName(p));` я же не спрашиваю, сложно ли вам найти как получить список файлов в каталоге и как достать имя файла из пути к нему.

Comment: @Davin да, сложно. Хотите помощь - попросите нормально, а не так будто Вам обязаны помочь на этом сайте